# Comparing two directories based on inodes

Tags: files, storage, inode, links

A bit of context that I think is relevant for the appropriate solution:

I have a server that has two folders; one is ingest, the other is sorted. The source of the sorted folder is the ingest folder, all directories are unique, all files are hard links.

The result of this is that when the ingest folder has a file deleted, it stays in the sorted folder, and vice versa. This makes cleanup almost impossible, as there are hundreds of thousands of files totaling about 40 terabytes.

I have a script to add all links to a database, with their inode and path name. I can then use some SQL to find the inodes that only appear once, and decide whether or not I want to delete them.

This solution is very slow (need to refresh the entire database every time I want to manage it) and quite clunky (need to run the query, then manually delete files over CLI).

Is there a solution like ncdu or any dual-pane file browser that can show inodes, and filter specifically on number of links for the inode (as shown by `stat`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now used `find . -type f -links +1` to get all the files with more than one link, then used `sed` to make all links absolute, and then `ncdu -X list.txt` to scan for any files except for those listed.

This solution is still slow and I am looking for a better one, but it does improve my process quite a bit already so I am posting it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do `ls -li` out to a file on both directories, then do a diff against it?

Comment: Because that still doesn't solve the issue of having an easy way to browse the result and delete files. Looking for some actual tool that is a little more dynamic than printing results and manually deleting them.

Comment: There is nothing, you need to roll your own. It's too unique a problem. If you have a diff, you can iterate through it and request whether it can be deleted or not. What's that, about 10 lines of bash code?

Comment: I already have a solution of my own that is more usable than just listing files and diffing, but what I'm trying to tackle is putting it in a usable and performant UI. 

Really if I could run ncdu and specifically filter files that only have one link, that would solve my issue. Hard to believe this wouldn't exist.